# Javascript transform date on timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

So I am trying to take a time that is application wide and display it in the user's timezone. Here is what I have worked up and it is working. However I am sure there is a better way to do this. The starting timezone will always be Central. Central = 5. I am only concerned with the US timezones but if there is an easy way to implement it worldwide I am down with that too. The text label I am working with will display like 4:00PM that is why there is so much substringing.

```
function timeZones() {
    var timezone = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    timezone = timezone / 60;
    //STARTING TIMEZONE WILL ALWAYS BE CENTRAL
    var difference = 5 - timezone;
    $(".time-zone").each(function () {
        var a = $(this).text();
        var hour = a.substring(0, a.indexOf(":") - 1);
        hour = parseInt(a);
        var yourTime;
        //East Coast
        if (difference == 1) {
            hour = hour + difference;
            if (hour == 12) {
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"), a.indexOf("A") - 1) + "PM";
            }
            else if (hour > 12) {
                hour = hour - 12;
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"), a.indexOf("A") - 1) + "PM";
            }
            else {
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"));
            }
            $(this).text(yourTime);
        }
        //Mountain
        if (difference == -1) {
            hour = hour + difference;
            if (hour == 0) {
                hour = 12;
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"));
            }
            else if (hour < 0) {
                hour = 12 + hour;
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"), a.indexOf("P") - 1) + "AM";
            }
            else {
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"));
            }
            $(this).text(yourTime);
        }
        //West Coast
        if (difference == -2) {
            hour = hour + difference;
            if (hour == 0) {
                hour = 12;
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"));
            }
            else if (hour < 0) {
                hour = 12 + hour;
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"), a.indexOf("P") - 1) + "AM";
            }
            else {
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"));
            }
            $(this).text(yourTime);
        }
        //Alaska
        if (difference == -3) {
            hour = hour + difference;
            if (hour == 0) {
                hour = 12;
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"));
            }
            else if (hour < 0) {
                hour = 12 + hour;
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"), a.indexOf("P") - 1) + "AM";
            }
            else {
                yourTime = hour + a.substring(a.indexOf(":"));
            }
            $(this).text(yourTime);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you should take a look at moment timezone library instead of trying to implement this.  It'll save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: There are so many out there. Which one would you recommend?

Comment: This is the one I was talking about: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> The starting timezone will always be Central. Central = 5.

That is incorrect.  A time zone and a time zone offset are *not* the same thing.  The US Central Time zone uses a UTC-6 offset in the winter, and uses a UTC-5 offset in the summer when [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) is in effect.  You cannot hard-code either of these.  See also, "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

If you need to work with non-local time zones in JavaScript, you'll need a library, such as those I list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).  For example, here is how you can achieve this using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) - which is an add on for the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library.

```
moment.tz('2014-10-02 01:23:00','America/Chicago').local().format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a')
```

In the above example, a local date/time in Chicago (US Central Time) is parsed.  Then it is converted to whatever time zone the user's browser is running in (with the `local` function).  Then it is formatted as a string according to the format specified.

Comment: 3 years later into my programming career I have learned to always use Momentjs and stop trying to re-design the wheel. To be honest the problem with this old code was that the company I was working for at the time didn't store their dates as UTC.

Answer (score 0):

Something I threw together

```
// timezone_out optional = local timezone
function timeConversionGenerator(timezone_in, timezone_out) {
    if (undefined === timezone_out)
        timezone_out = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    var d = timezone_in - timezone_out;
    return function (time) {
        var hh = time.hh,
            mm = time.mm + d,
            ss = time.ss;
        while (mm <   0) mm += 60, hh -= 1;
        while (mm >= 60) mm -= 60, hh += 1;
        while (hh <   0) hh += 24;
        hh %= 24;
        return {
            hh: hh,
            mm: mm,
            ss: ss
        };
    }
}

var c = timeConversionGenerator(5 * 60); // 5 hours behind UTC to local time
```

Now

```
c({
    hh: 13,
    mm: 18,
    ss: 0
});
/* converted to my local time (British Summer Time)
{
   hh: 19,
   mm: 18,
   ss: 0
}
*/
```

Then

```
function toAMPMString(time) {
    return ((time.hh % 12) || 12)
        + ':'
        + (time.mm < 10 ? '0' : '') + time.mm
        + ' ' + (time.hh < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM');
}

// so
toAMPMString(c({ hh: 13, mm: 18, ss: 0})); // "7:18 PM"
```